# mean square error calculated from prcomp output

Tags: r, pca

Assuming a simulation `x`(some equation) is performed,  the output for `pcX <-prcomp(x, scale = True, center = True)` is  the standard deviation and rotation of the matrix. The `summary(pcX)` would show the standard deviation along with the proportion of variance and cumulative proportion output. I would like to extract mean square error from these output.

The basic properties of [mse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) mentions that if we would like to calculate `mse`,  we need to have an actual value and a predict value. Also, most of the examples online they have a prediction/training value/data. Inside `?prcomp` there is a `predict (object, newdata, ...)` code. In general, if we would like to extract/calculate the mse from `prcomp`, is it compulsory to have a predict value as well?

Comment: To what would your mse apply?  Since PCA doesn't predict anything, nor does it simulate anything, it is difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to know whether `prcomp` function can extract mean square error without having to do any prediction or data training. In wikipedia, if we are using a covariance method, the `mse` can be calculate. But does this applies only to that method? How about `prcomp`? I understand that it uses SVD approach.

Comment: Still unclear. Try asking not about software, but about stats. To use PCA you need data, and a model with parameters. Tell us about your data and models, please.